# Need assistance with closest in a dynamic menu

Tags: closest

I've built a dynamic menu with php with categories and subcategories.
The php part works fine,
I need help to add an activelink class to the correct a tag in the menu by getting the page url.

This is my code:

On the page in order to get the category and subcategory:

```
<script>
var catnum = '<?php echo $catnum;?>';
var subnum = '<?php echo $subid;?>';
</script>
```

So far so good.
Js page:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#cat"+catnum+"LI").addClass("active");
$("#cat"+catnum+"UL").addClass("in");
$("#cat"+catnum+"LI").attr("style", "display:block");

var subcatnum = 'subcat.php?id='+subnum;

$("#cat"+catnum+"UL" + ">li").each(function() {

    var navItem = $(this);
    var templink = navItem.find("a").attr("href");
        if(templink == subcatnum){
            navItem.closest('.title').addClass('activeli'); // This does not seem to work            }
});
```

});

The purpose is to highlight the active span on the page.

This is the html:

```
<ul id="side-nav" class="main-menu navbar-collapse collapse">
    <li><a href="dashboard.php" title="לוח הבקרה"><i class="icon-gauge"></i><span class="title">לוח הבקרה</span></a></li>

            <li class="has-sub" id="cat18LI"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><span class="title">1111111112</span></a>
            <ul class="nav collapse" id="cat18UL">

                <li><a href="subcat.php?id=3"><span class="title">תת קטגוריה 3</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="subcat.php?id=5"><span class="title">בדיקהdfsfsdfsdfds</span></a></li>

        </ul>
         </li>
            <li class="has-sub active" id="cat15LI" style="display:block"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cog"></i><span class="title">בדיקה</span></a>
            <ul class="nav collapse in" id="cat15UL">

                <li><a href="subcat.php?id=1"><span class="title">תת קטגוריה ניסיון</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="subcat.php?id=2"><span class="title">תת קטגוריה שנערכה</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="subcat.php?id=8"><span class="title">בדיקה</span></a></li>

                <li><a href="subcat.php?id=9"><span class="title">נערך</span></a></li>

  </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
    var subcatnum = 'subcat.php?id='+subnum;

$("#cat"+catnum+"UL" + ">li").each(function() {

    var navItem = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        console.log("navItem :" + navItem);
        console.log("subcatnum :" + subcatnum);
    if(subcatnum === navItem){
        $(this).children('a').addClass('activelink');
    }
});
```